# Is using "they are" grammatically correct when referencing a single person?

Tags: pronouns

Is using "they are" grammatically correct when referencing a singular person? Like for example, "They are going to go to the grocery store". If it's not then is using you're or you are not correct?

Comment: I have corrected your spelling of **grammatically** and I suspect that you are referring to a single person rather than a singular one.

Comment: You should try to do some research before asking and indicate what you may have already learned and why you still need more help. "Singular they" is discussed **extensively** on the Internet, in grammar books, and on this site.

Answer (score 2):

If a male person is going to the grocery store, you can say 'he is going'. If it's a female person you can say 'she is going'. 'He' and 'she' are gender-specific pronouns.

If any of these are true, you can say 'they are going'. 'They'  here is used as a singular, non-gender-specific or gender-neutral pronoun:

- You don't know what sex they are
- You don't wish to mention their sex
- Their sex is not important
- You know that the person does not identify as male or female

If you speak to a person of any sex, you say 'you are' or 'you're'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @user152846 - see edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

You use “they” absolutely correctly for a single person, in these situations:

1. The person is quite likely male or female, but you have no idea which. Nobody saw the burglar, but they escaped with $10,000.
2. The person is quite likely male or female, but it doesn’t matter in what you are saying. One hotel guest caused much damage; they smoked in their room and set the curtains on fire.
3. We are talking about an abstract person. When a guest arrives, the concierge will pick up their luggage from their car and bring it to their room.
4. We are talking about a person who for any reason doesn’t want to be classified as “male” or “female”.

Each use is grammatically correct, just like we use the plural “you” for a single person.